# Slick Slider Images not resizing correctly on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, image-resizing, microsoft-edge

hope you can help with this...

I'm using Slick slider to display some images. The images on the slider should change size dependent on the size of the screen, this works fine on Chrome and Firefox but when I try to view on MS Edge The full size layout works but the layout which has been optimized for tablets and phones shows the slider images sitting in the top left corner of the available space. I can't work out why they wouldn't take up 100% of the available width as they do on the other browsers.

The code I'm using is as follows:

HTML

```
<!--Image slider-->
        <div id="portfolio-container" class="slider">
            <div class="slide"><img src="graphics/example01.svg" alt="Example" title="Example"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="graphics/example02.svg" alt="Example" title="Example"></div>
            <div class="slide"><img src="graphics/example03.svg" alt="Example" title="Example"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
#portfolio-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#portfolio-container img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3500,
        infinity: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        responsive: [
            {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 3500,
                infinity: true,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            }
        }
        ]
      });
});
```

Comment: Just ran into this exact problem over two years later. Did you ever figure it out?